# Probability function for difference between two i.i.d. Exponential r.v.s

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, density-function

My answer is completely off. Can you please tell me where did my logic go wrong.

Donald Trump and Tori Black are to meet at a specific time and both will be late by $ \sim Exponential(\lambda), i.i.d. $.  What is the cdf of the arrival time difference.

Let $ X, Y$ be the late time and difference be $Z = X - Y$. Cases are $z \geq 0$ and $z < 0 $.

First, for $ z \geq 0$,

$ F_Z(z) = P(Z\leq z) = P(X-Y \leq z) = 1 - P(X-Y > z) = 1 - P(X>Z+Y)$

Z $\geq 0$, so $X \geq 0 $ for all $Y$.

$$\begin{align} F_Z(z) & = 1 - \int_0^\infty(\int_{z+y}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx) dy \\& = 1 - \int_0^\infty(\int_{z+y}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda y}\cdot\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx) dy \\& = 1 - \int_0^\infty\lambda e^{-\lambda y}(-e^{-\lambda x}|_{z+y}^\infty) dy \\& = 1 - \int_0^\infty\lambda e^{-2\lambda y}e^{-\lambda z}dy \\& = 1 - e^{-\lambda z}\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-2\lambda y} \\& = 1 - \frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda z}\end{align}$$

Now, for $z < 0$, where my calculation went **very wrong**.

Similarly, $F_Z(z) = 1 - P(X-Y > z) = 1 - P(X>Z+Y) $

$Z < 0$, so  for $X \geq 0$, $Y$ should be $Y \geq -Z$, so I do:

$$\begin{align}F_Z(z) & = 1 - \int_{-z}^\infty(\int_{z+y}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda y}\cdot\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx) dy \\& = 1- \int_{-z}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda y}\cdot e^{-\lambda (z+y)}dy \\& = 1 - e^{- \lambda z}\int_{-z}^\infty \lambda e^{-2\lambda y}dy \\& = 1 - e^{-\lambda z}\cdot \frac{1}{2}e ^{2\lambda z} \\& = 1 - \frac{1}{2}e^{\lambda z}.\end{align}$$

Hence, my answers for both cases are the same except the $z$ sign.

The correct CDFs are given in textbook as

$F_Z(z) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda z}$ for $z\geq 0$ and $\frac{1}{2}e^{\lambda z}$ for $z<0$.

---

I forgot to integrate $Y$ over $\int_0^{-z}$ for $z<0$, which when included gives the textbook answer.

Comment: In your last line, you have $x$ for $z.$ Perhaps see [Wikipedia on Laplace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) distributions.

Comment: Can’t you just answer ‘Poisson’?  Exponential waiting times are distributed Poison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral limits are not correct. If you draw the region of integration, it'll be in the first quadrant and to the right of the line $X-Y=z$. It'll be easier to integrate if the order of integration is $dy dx$. Otherwise, you'd need to calculate two different ranges: $0\leq y \leq -z$ and $-z<y<\infty$. In your integral, you just calculate the second interval.

$$\begin{align}P(X>z+Y)&=\int_0^\infty \int_0^{x-z}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\lambda e^{-\lambda y}dydx\\&=\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\lambda(x-z)})dx\\&=1-e^{\lambda z}\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-2\lambda x}dx\\&=1-e^{\lambda z}/2\end{align}$$

This yields $F_Z(z)=e^{\lambda z}/2$

Comment: Right! I only integrated $Y$ using $\int_{-z}^\infty$, leaving the part below $-z$ behind. For $Z<0, \int_{-z}^\infty \int_{z+y}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dxdy + \int_0^{-z} \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dxdy = \frac{1}{2}e^{\lambda z} + (-e^{\lambda z} + 1)$. Subtracting them from 1, $-\frac{1}{2}e^{\lambda z}+e^{\lambda z} = \frac{1}{2}e^{\lambda z}$

Answer (score 2):

I will not answer the OP's question as to where his analysis for the case $z<0$ went wrong but instead point out an easier way of getting to the correct answer once the value of $F_Z(z)$ has been determined to be $1-\frac 12 \exp(-\lambda z)$ when $z > 0$.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. random variables, the *density* of $Z = X-Y$ must be the same as the density of $-Z = Y-X$, that is, the density must be an *even* function. One consequence of this is that $P(Z>\alpha) = P(Z<-\alpha)$ and so we immediately get
\begin{align} P(Z > z) &= \frac 12 \exp(-\lambda z), &z > 0,\\
&{\big \Downarrow}\\ 
P(Z < -z) &= \frac 12 \exp(-\lambda z), &z > 0,\\
&{\big \Downarrow}\\ 
P(Z < z) &= \frac 12 \exp(\lambda z), &z < 0,\\
\end{align}
and so,  $$F_Z(z) = P(Z \leq z) = P(Z < z) = \frac 12 \exp(\lambda z), \,\,\,\ z < 0.$$

Comment: That's what the textbook does. I can 'tell' $Z = X-Y$ is symmetrical such that $-Z =^d Y-X$. $$ \\ F_Z(z) = P(Z\leq z) = P(-Z\leq -z) = P(Z\leq -z) = 1-F_Z(-z). \\$$ $z<0$ so $-z>0$, then applying the $F_Z(z)$ for $z\geq 0$ in $1-F_Z(-z)$ will give $F_Z(z)$ for $z<0$. $\\$ Symmetry here is obvious, but issue is I am not sure if I can always tell 'symmetry'.

Comment: @ABC Analytics it is symmetric because $X$ and $Y$ are similarly distributed variables and their roles can be swapped. If the variables would have a different $\lambda$ parameter then it wouldn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this problem can be solved without computing any integrals at all if you start from the knowledge that the exponential distribution is the *only* continuous distribution which has no memory. That means if a random variable $X\sim\text{Expon}(\lambda)$ then also $X-a|X>a\sim\text{Expon}(\lambda)$ for any $a>0$. In other words, if $X$ is the time until Donald Trump arrives and he has not arrived after, say, 10 minutes, then time until he arrives beyond those 10 minutes is *also* distributed as $X$. This may seem counterintuitive but is easy to prove.

Now if $X,Y$ are iid $\text{Expon}(\lambda)$ and the arrival time of Donald and Tori respectively, then Donald will be the first to arrive with probability 0.5: $\text{Prob}(Y>X)=0.5$. More importantly in that case however, the memoryless property of $Y$ tells us that $Y-X|Y>X \sim\text{Expon}(\lambda)$ whatever the value of $X$ and therefore $-Z|Y>X$ is $\text{Expon}(\lambda)$. Likewise, if Tori arrives first, with probability $\text{Prob}[X>Y]=0.5$, then $Z|X>Y$ is also $\text{Expon}(\lambda)$. Bringing together the two cases gives you the symmetrical  result for $F_Z(z)$ that was obtained before.

Comment: You might make this correspond to an integration (which might be necessary if you wish to proof the property of having memory). Then you get $$P(X>z+Y|X>Y) = \int_0^\infty P(X>z+Y|X>Y,Y=y)f_Y(y)   dy$$ or $$P(X>z+Y|X>Y) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\int_{z+y}^\infty f_X(x)  dx } {\int_{y}^\infty f_X(x)  dx }f_Y(y)dy$$ where ratio of integrals is a term independent of y and can be taken outside the integral. This contrasts with $$P(X>z+Y) = \int_0^\infty P(X>z+Y|Y=y)f_Y(y)   dy = \int_0^\infty  {\int_{z+y}^\infty f_X(x)  dx } f_Y(y)dy$$ which does not have that ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I asked for **cdf** but if it were for **pdf**.

For $z\geq 0, 0\leq z\leq x <\infty$,
$$\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= \int_z^\infty f_X(x)\cdot f_y(x-z)dx \\
& = \lambda^2 e^{\lambda z}\int_z^\infty e^{-2\lambda x}dx \\
&= \frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda z}
\end{align}$$

For $z<0, z< 0\leq x <\infty$,
$$\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= \int_0^\infty f_X(x)\cdot f_y(x-z)dx \\
& = \lambda^2 e^{\lambda z}\int_0^\infty e^{-2\lambda x}dx \\
&= \frac{\lambda}{2}e^{\lambda z}
\end{align}$$