# Unexpected distribution of ab-cd where a,b,c,d are independent and N(0,1) distributed

Tags: normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

I have discovered an unexpected curiosity that if
a,b,c,d are independent random variables and are N(0,1) distributed, then
|ab-cd| is exponentially distributed Exp(1). It's easy to verify that numerically.
Is there a proof of that ? or does it stem from some deeper fact ?

I noticed that it when I was considering cross products of random Gaussian distributed vectors and noticed that their components have \exp(-|x|/a) distribution.

Demonstration with python

```py
N = 1000000
x = np.random.normal(size=(N,4))
z = np.abs(x[:,0] * x[:,1] - x[:,2] * x[:,3])
plt.hist(scipy.stats.expon.cdf(z), bins=100)
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, $ab-cd$ has a standard Laplace distribution (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/71126/119261), and absolute value of that is known to be standard exponential.

Comment: @Stubborn Thank you!  I had vaguely recalled that thread but couldn't find it.  We ought to consider it a duplicate, because it is so obvious from the symmetry of the standard Normal distribution that $ab-cd$ and $ab+cd$ are identically distributed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this result (that ab+cd is Laplace) is in Kendall and Stuart Vol 1, 3rd edition (though unfortunately I can't double check this easily at present).

Comment: Thanks, @Glen.  I found it in two places in K&S.  One was a mere (unproven) assertion; the other is an exercise.  I have quoted that exercise in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing

$$ab - cd = \left(\left[\left(\frac{a+b}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{c+d}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2 \right] - \left[\left(\frac{a-b}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2  + \left(\frac{c-d}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2 \right]\right)/2$$

and noting that $(a+b, c+d, a-b, c-d)/\sqrt{2}$ has a standard Normal distribution, it is immediate (from the definitions of chi-square distributions arising from sums of squares of independent standard Normal variables) that *the distribution of $ab -cd$ is twice that of the difference of two independent chi-squared(2) variables.*

Since chi-squared(2) variables have Exponential$(1/2)$ distributions, $ab-cd$ is distributed as the difference of two Exponential$(1)$ distributions.  Since the characteristic function of an Exponential$(1)$ distribution is $\phi(t) = 1/(1 - it),$ the cf. of  the difference is

$$\phi(t)\phi(-t) = \frac{1}{1+t^2}.$$

The Fourier Transform of that is proportional to $f(\omega)=\exp(-|\omega|),$ showing that the absolute value $|ab-cd|$ must have a density proportional to $f(x)$ for $x\ge 0:$ that's the Exponential$(1)$ distribution.

The thread at [Probability function for difference between two i.i.d. Exponential r.v.s](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/483542) gives a direct demonstration of this latter result *via* integration of the convolution.

#### Reference

(Courtesy Glen B: see comments to the question.)

The symmetry of standard Normal distributions around zero and the independence of $d$ from $(a,b,c)$ imply $(a,b,c,-d)$ has the same distribution as $(a,b,c,d),$ whence the distribution of $|ab-cd|$ is the same as that of $|ab-c(-d)|=|ab+cd|.$

A brief analysis of the question in this form appears in Stuart & Ord, *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics* Volume I (3rd Ed. 1987) in the first half of exercise 11.21:

> $x_r,y_r,$ $r=1,2,\ldots,$ are independent standardized normal variates.  Show that $z= x_1y_1 + x_2y_2$ is distributed exactly as $w_1-w_2,$ where the $w_j$ are independent with f.f. [probability density] $e^{-w_j}$ [NB: only for $w_j\ge 0$] and hence or otherwise that $z$ is distributed in the Laplace form $g(z)=\frac{1}{2}\exp\left(-|z|\right),$ and that $|z|$ is again exponentially distributed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the derivations and pointers.

Answer (score 4):

There is an extensive theory on the properties of [random matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix), including the distribution of their determinants.

From the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268149/determinant-of-real-wishart-matrix) for example you can see that if you form the matrix $W=AA^T$, where the elements of $A$ are your $\mathcal N (0,1)$ random variables, then

$$ \det W \sim \chi^2_2 \chi^2_1 $$

namely the determinant of $W$ has the distribution of a product of two independent $\chi^2$ random variables with 2 and 1 degrees of freedom.
The distribution of the product can be derived using the equivalent distribution of a [product of Gamma random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables#Gamma_distributions). In the general case this is expressed in terms of a modified Bessel functions, but here it reduces to a simpler expression, and using the transformation $|\det A|=\sqrt{\det W}$ it can be worked out quite easily that indeed $|\det A|$ has an exponential distribution with mean 1.

There might be a more direct and maybe simpler way of driving this property that i'm missing at the moment - maybe someone else can find it.